# how to show sub-menu when using the scroll bar on a sub menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My submenu doesn`t show up when I have scroll bar. I am using bootstrap

[image]

this is my html code:

```
<a tabindex="-1" href="#">Location</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu  scrollable-menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">Afghanistan</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
                                            <li><a class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Select all</a></li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>

                                        </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
```

This is my css code:

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 405px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: can you show a working demo in jsfiddle so that its easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **height: auto;** and  **overflow-x: hidden;**

Try these bellow code:

```
 .scrollable-menu {
    max-height: 400px;  
    overflow: auto; /* Scrollbar */ 
  }
```

Updated Code:

```
 .scrollable-menu ul li ul {
    max-height: 400px;  
    overflow: auto; /* Scrollbar */ 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scrollable-menu {
    max-height: 405px;
    overflow-x: auto; /* or overflow:scroll */
}
```

Comment: Hi Syam,  I am also facing same issue. Could please update here? how did you fix?